# How do I change the default location for nushell configration files

Tags: macos, nushell

I noticed the default location for nushell's configuration files on Mac OS is `~/Library/Application Support/nushell/`, is it possible to change it to another location?

Answer (score 2):

Issuing `nu --help` gives the option

```bash
--config <String> - start with an alternate config file
```

So, starting it with `nu --config another/location/config.nu` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Only symbolic link worked for me on macos m1:

```shell
mv ~/Library/Application\ Support/nushell ~/.config/
ln -s ~/.config/nushell ~/Library/Application\ Support/
```

- https://github.com/nushell/nushell/issues/10746
- https://github.com/nushell/nushell/issues/893

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to set the `NU_CONFIG_DIR` environment variable to the desired directory path,so if you are using bash open `nano ~/.bash_profile` or if you are using zsh open nano `~/.zprofile` and put this line into it :

```
export NU_CONFIG_DIR=/path/to/custom/location
```

now save and exit then apply the changes to your current shell session like below if you are under bash :

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and if you are under zsh

```
source ~/.zprofile
```

that's it,nushell will use the specified directory (`/path/to/custom/location`) as the location for its configuration files, such as `config.toml` and `history.txt`!

Comment: may I ask what is `config.toml` for? It wasn't mentioned in the [configuration](https://www.nushell.sh/book/configuration.html).

Comment: sure,`config.toml` file is a configuration file used by nushell, a modern shell for the command-line interface and it allows you to define and modify settings, but it's important to note that it is optional, and nushell will use default settings if the file is not present or if specific settings are not defined within it.

Comment: does not work on macos